# Do I need an article in a main element

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm wondering if it's best practice to use the `article` element for pages that have only a single article made up of just a couple of paragraphs of text (i.e. an article without sections). Is there, semantically speaking, anything wrong with putting all the content in a `main` element, without an `article`?

To illustrate, is there anything wrong with this:

```
<main>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p>Vivamus ut eros vulputate...</p>
  <p>In tincidunt a neque rutrum dapibus...</p>
</main>
```

Or is this better:

```
<main>
  <article>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  <p>Vivamus ut eros vulputate...</p>
  <p>In tincidunt a neque rutrum dapibus...</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an `article` within a `main` if it's the only one; the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element) says that it's redundant in such a case. But there's nothing wrong with having one, and it can be useful for when your pages are dynamically templated and generated, and your articles are always templated with `article` elements.

Answer (score 1):

#### `main` element

You can ignore the `main` element for making this decision, because it doesn’t have an effect on the sections/outline.

#### Difference between your snippets

Your two snippets create different document outlines ([you can test it with this Web app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2191/60)):

```
1. "Lorem ipsum"
```

vs.

```
1. Document
  1.1 "Lorem ipsum"
```

Your second snippet doesn’t provide a heading element for the `body` (which is a sectioning root element), so an implicit heading is created (i.e., *Document*).

The `h1` in your first snippet is the heading for the `body` (i.e., the whole document). This can make sense in some cases (e.g., when it’s stand-alone page that only contains the article), but for your typical website (which contains global navigation, sidebars, etc.), you typically want to have your site name as document heading.

#### tl;dr

If your page is a stand-alone document, not part of a website:

```html
<body>

  <main>
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p></p>
  </main>

</body>
```

If you have typical webpage that’s part of a website (with global navigation):

```html
<body>

  <h1>My site</h1>

  <main>
    <article>
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p></p>
    </article>
  </main>

  <nav>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at MDN it doesn't appear that it is necessary. It does have a few things that you can't do.

"`<main>` must not be a descendent of an `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>`, or `<nav>` element.
Only one `main` element can be used per document"

Here's the page I was looking at "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main"

I'd say if it validates then you're fine.